# XUL Overlay for Preferences

Tags: firefox, overlay, xul

I'm trying to make a XUL overlay for Preferences for my extension. I have the following code as part of my overlay, but it is still not appearing under Firefox->Preferences:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css"  type="text/css"?>

  <overlay id="tabularity-browser-overlay"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

        <prefwindow id="BrowserPreferences">
          <prefpane id="tabularityPane" label="tabularityPane;" 
                    onpaneload="populateSchedulesList()" 
        image="chrome://tabulationtwo/content/images/tab.png">
    <preferences>
            <preference id="perSession"
               name="extensions.tabulation.defaultHomepage"
       type="bool"/>
            </preferences>
    <radiogroup>
      <radio preference="perSession" id="session" label="Open tabs once per session" accesskey="S" selected="true"/>
      <radio preference="perSession" id="instance" label="Open tabs every tab instance"  accesskey="I"/>
    </radiogroup>
          </prefpane>
        </prefwindow>
```

Can anyone help me diagnose the problem or point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check here, it's working for me:[url=http://postimage.org/image/ekouj12d3/][img]http://s7.postimage.org/ekouj12d3/Screen_Shot_2012_12_09_at_11_31_13_AM.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: I have checked it, the overlay ending tag is missing : </overlay>

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is only part of the code, there is more XUL underneath it, with an </overlay> tag further down. This is just for the preference box. Everything else works fine. I can't see the image you posted, but I will try loading my code into another profile.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this solution to show the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css"  type="text/css"?>

  <overlay id="tabularity-browser-overlay"
xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

        <prefwindow id="BrowserPreferences">
          <prefpane id="tabularityPane" label="tabularityPane;"
                    onpaneload="populateSchedulesList()"
        image="chrome://tabulationtwo/content/images/tab.png">
    <preferences>
            <preference id="perSession"
               name="extensions.tabulation.defaultHomepage"
       type="bool"/>
            </preferences>
    <radiogroup>
      <radio preference="perSession" id="session" label="Open tabs once per session" accesskey="S" selected="true"/>
      <radio preference="perSession" id="instance" label="Open tabs every tab instance"  accesskey="I"/>
    </radiogroup>
          </prefpane>
        </prefwindow>
</overlay>
```

If you would like to know, how to handle please refer this link : 
[Menu bar overlay in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561237/menu-bar-overlay-in-firefox/7565506#7565506)
http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001606.html
Image: [image]